# ARM Template: how to read output result in array format

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I posted some question on stackoverflow and would like to thanks those who take time to answer.
Although it exists documentation, i still face an issue related to output feature.

Basically I understand how to retrieve data when format is *string*.
Unfortunately when data is on *array* format it looks more difficult for me.

```
 "outputs": {
    "keyVaultName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('keyVaultName')]"
    },
    "websitesname": {
        "type": "array",
        "copy": {
            "count": "[length(variables('webSitesName'))]",
            "input": {
                "name": "[variables('webSitesName')[copyIndex()].name]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then i do this:

```
$deploymentResult = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deploymentName -ResourceGroupName 
$ResourceGroupName-TemplateFile $TemplateFile 
$vaultName = $deploymentResult.Outputs.keyVaultName.Value
$arrayWebsitesName = $deploymentResult.Outputs.websitesname.Value
```

[image]

I need to extract value from returned array. In powershell i expected to use something like

- $arrayWebsitesName[0] to get AppService-Prod-CentralUS
- $arrayWebsitesName[\1] to get AppService-Prod-EastUS

I believe there is something related to conversion and I tried convertto-json without success.
Your help is appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable type returned from the deployment for `websitesname` is a `JArray`.

```
PS> $deploymentResult.Outputs.websitesname.Value.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    JArray                                   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer
```

In order to get at the values, you would make the call like:

```
$arrayWebsitesName = $deploymentResult.Outputs.websitesname.Value
$ids = $arrayWebsitesName.ToString() | ConvertFrom-Json
$ids[0].name
$ids[1].name
```

Converting the JArray to a JSON string, and then converting the JSON string to a PowerShell array may not be most efficient but I don't typically deal with large arrays and performance is not a concern (gets the job done).

Comment: Simply awesome. Thanks Stringfellow for your valuable help on all queries i posted. 
It helps me to appreciate ARM template.